# How do we get the very nearest landmark based on lat and long in google map API?

Tags: google-api

I have a Requirement based on the above question of getting very nearest Landmark of a given Latitude and Longitude in google map api v3. Would any one knows, Please share to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you would call a "landmark".

The easiest way is to use the Google Places library. You'll find an introduction here, with a full example for a "search nearby":
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

You'll then need to pick the types of places which you would consider landmarks. You'll find the list of possible types here:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

Comment: Thank you for giving answers

Comment: @user3655988, if any answer was helpful, don't forget to up vote and/or accept it :-)